# MySQLi query - php - html form: query line obtained from html form is different from hard-coded query line?

Tags: php, html, apache

I am building website with a login page. The login page has a html form as shown, the html file is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/my-site/LoginPage/loginPageGraphics.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="frmLogin" method="post" action="/my-site/LoginPage/login.php" accept-charset="UTF-8"/>
        <div id="loginField">
            <div>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/my-site/LoginPage/loginPageAction.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/my-site/database/databaseActions.js"></script>
                <p>
                    <input id="txtUsername" name="username" type="text" placeholder="username"/> <br/>
                    <input id="txtPassword" name="password" type="password" placeholder="password"/> <br/>
                    <input id="btnLogin" type="submit" value="Login"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="query" value="SELECT ID, Fname, Lname, Username, Password, Type FROM user_accounts WHERE Username='$Username'"/>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div>   <!--This div block has no code behind it yet. It is just there for now.-->
                <p>
                    <input id="btnCreateAccount" type="submit" value="Create Account" onclick="createAccount(txtUsername.value, txtPassword.value)"/> <br/>
                    Create admin account? <input id="chbCreateAdmin" type="checkbox"/>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When the submit button btnLogin is clicked, the form runs a php script, login.php

```
<?php //this is login.php
$Query = $_POST["query"]; //Query line from html form
$Username = $_POST["username"];

//This 'hard-coded' query is the exact same as the query line from html form
$Query1 = "SELECT ID, Fname, Lname, Username, Password, Type FROM user_accounts WHERE Username='$Username'"; //hard-coded query line
echo $Query;//There is only 1 difference between these two echos. This echo displays "... Username='$Username'"; //$Username is the variable that holds the entered user name
echo $Query1;//                                             While this echo displays "... Username='TylerB'";  //TylerB is the entered username
if($Query === $Query1){
    echo "true";
}elseif($Query == $Query1){
    echo"true2";
}else{
    echo"false"; //this one gets echoed
}

require "../database/dbConnection.php"; //the contents of this file is below. I am using require, as I want this php file to be re-usable.
/*  |___>   require "DB.php"; //The DB.php file holds the database login info

            $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $dbName); //Variables specified in DB.php
            if($conn->connect_error){
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }
            $result = $conn->query($Query); 
*/

/*$Query: $result has 0 num_rows
$Query1: $result has 1 num_rows  (this is expected)
This information was found via var_dump($results); The lines of codes was removed a little while ago*/
if($result->num_rows > 0){ //If num_rows is equal to 1, no account with the entered username was found 
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        if($_POST["password"] === $row["Password"]){//If entered password matchs the selected account's password, login to home page
            if($row["Type"] === "Admin"){//Purpose of this if statement is not relevant to the question. Just know, if login info is correct, user logins to a home page.
                echo "go to admin home page";
            }else{
                echo "go to student home page";
            }
        }else{//if password is incorrect
            echo "ERROR: Username or password was incorrect. Please enter the correct account information.";
        }
    }
}else{//if username is incorrect
    echo "ERROR: Username or password was incorrect. Please enter the correct account information.";
} 
?>
```

When I use the variable $Query1, the website runs correctly. However, when I use $Query, $result 's num_rows is 0. In otherwords, it didn't find an account with the username TylerB (despite that $Query1 does find an account with the username TylerB).

The only difference that echos between $Query1 and $Query at the end of the query line: (See top of login.php file for more info about these two variables)

```
echo $Query;//There is only 1 difference between these two echos. This echo displays "... Username='$Username'"; //$Username is the variable that holds the entered user name
echo $Query1;//                                                While this echo displays "... Username='TylerB'";  //TylerB is the entered username
```

My questions...

Why are the two query variables giving two different query results? How do I fix this?

I suspect this is mainly revolving around the two slightly different echos for $Query and $Query1. Is the $Username in "... WHERE Username='$Username'" being queried instead of $Username's value? (I doubt this myself...)

If it is, how should I approach this? The query line that dbConnection.php requires needs to come from another source, otherwise it will be specific to the login page. Which is the exact opposite of my intentions - having dbConnection.php re-usable any wheres when a query is needed.

Versions/programs etc:

Sublime 3

Apache web server (all in one package from http://www.wampserver.com/en/  Used WAMPSERVER (64 BITS & PHP 5.6.15 $ PHP 7)

PHP 7

Google Chrome

MySQL

JS

CSS

Windows 10

---------------------------------------------EDIT-------------------------------

While there isn't as much re-usable code as I was going for. I can still work with what I have. However, regarding all the comments around safety and hacking... How safe is this code?

```
    <form name="frmLogin" method="post" action="/my-site/LoginPage/login.php" accept-charset="UTF-8"/>
        <div id="loginField">
            <div>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/my-site/LoginPage/loginPageAction.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/my-site/database/databaseActions.js"></script>
                <p>
                    <input id="txtUsername" name="username" type="text" placeholder="username"/> <br/>
                    <input id="txtPassword" name="password" type="password" placeholder="password"/> <br/>
                    <input id="btnLogin" type="submit" value="Login"/>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div> 
                <p>
                    <input id="btnCreateAccount" type="submit" value="Create Account" onclick="createAccount(txtUsername.value, txtPassword.value)"/> <br/>
                    Create admin account? <input id="chbCreateAdmin" type="checkbox"/>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Submit runs the following...

```
<?php
$User = $_POST["username"];

require "../database/dbConnection.php";
/*  |
<?php
    require "DB.php";
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $dbName);
    if($conn->connect_error){
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
?>*/
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID, Fname, Lname, Username, Password, Type FROM user_accounts WHERE Username=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $User);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($ID, $Fname, $Lname, $Username, $Password, $Type);
$stmt->fetch();

if($User === $Username){
    if($_POST["password"] === $Password){
        if($Type === "Admin"){
            echo "go to admin home page";
        }else{
            echo "go to student home page";
        }
    }else{
        echo "ERROR: Username or password was incorrect. Please enter the correct account information.";
    }
}else{
    echo "ERROR: Username or password was incorrect. Please enter the correct account information.";
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm wondering why you're using `value="SELECT ID, Fname, Lname, Username, Password, Type FROM user_accounts WHERE Username='$Username'"` in the first place. Look at your HTML source and check for errors everywhere; being via PHP and MySQL.

Comment: That hard-coded line was just for testing. I want my dbConnection.php to be re-usable. I believe whenever a query is required, there will be a form that can pass information to the php files with the get/post and $_POST. So I decided to have a hidden input with the query line. However, I ran into an issue, and that led me to use $Query1=query line; so I can learn more what is happening in the program.

Comment: Making the SQL query visible in the form is VERY bad practice, it opens security holes as large as a barn door. Just don't do it.

Comment: The type attribute hidden hides it right? ...

Comment: sure, until someone looks at the source code. It is not shown in plain sight,  but it is just as visible.

Comment: okay, well how should I approach what I want to do: dbConnection.php getting a query line from another location in the program?

Comment: to add to the above...someone could easily modify or spoof that value to run whatever SQL they desire. It might not be SQL _you_ desire of course. This is a crazy design that will get you hacked

Comment: You're talking about the injection hack? That's something I plan to prevent after this page is working.

Comment: I would start again using PDO and parameterised prepared statements or stored procedures. There are dozens of tutorials on the net showing how to do this. It will make your code much safer, (and easier to re-use queries in different places, since you asked about how to get queries to run from different places)

Comment: Hi already use mysqli, why hi need to switch to PDO?
mysqli has prepared statements (and it's newer emulate them, PDO sometimes just emulate them) + mysqli can run querys asynchronously (PDO can't do this).

Comment: Well, I've updated a few sections in the code (displayed at bottom of original post). Regarding all the unsafe comments, I am wondering how safe is the new code?

Comment: Much better, now it's impossible to change your query, and prepared statements protects you from sql injection. Probably, It still vulnerable for CSRF.

Comment: Well, as to my understanding from this website I just read. There are things I was already planning to do that should prevent/limit the possibility for this CSRF hack. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Never put "solved", "answered", or "ANSWERED IN COMMENTS" within the title.  Posting an answer below in the Answers section and "accepting" it is how visitors will know this is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My questions was answered in the OP comments, the overall answer is at this link:

[MySQLi query - php - html form: query line obtained from html form is different from hard-coded query line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38101062/mysqli-query-php-html-form-query-line-obtained-from-html-form-is-different#comment63638009_38101062)